# how can one restore a file that disappeared after git checkout -b

Tags: git

I did the following:

1. git clone [fork]
2. worked for a few days, creating new files 1 & 2
3. git add newfile1
4. git add newfile2
5. git checkout -b new_branch
6. git checkout master

At this point, I expected newfile1 and newfile2 to be waiting for me, but they are not.  Everything has reverted back to the original master, as what is currently on the github server.

Is my work waiting for me somewhere?  Or has it become a recycled bunch of bits?

Comment: If you run `git status` do the new files show up as `changes to be committed`?

Comment: The `git checkout -b master` seems suspect as there should already be a `master` branch.  Maybe there is a typo on this line and maybe there is a branch that is closely named to `master` that has `newfile1` and `newfile2`.  What does `git branch` show?

Comment: good catch, I meant that...figuratively.  It was the initial git clone of the fork.

Comment: torek:  no, the files do not show up to be committed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After repeating your steps my `git status` shows me

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   newfile1
#       new file:   newfile2
#
```

This mean, that you did something else to your repository, that you didn't considered important nor potentially harmful.

And now to your actual question: Yes, you might be able to do it.

- First do a complete backup of your `.git` directory
- Create a file `all-objects.sh` with this script (source: https://gist.github.com/ctindall/4588884)

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  set -e

  cd "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)"

  # Find all the objects that are in packs:

  if [ "$(ls -A .git/objects/pack)" ]
  then
      for p in .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx
          do
                  git show-index < $p | cut -f 2 -d ' '
          done
  fi

  # And now find all loose objects:

  find .git/objects/ | egrep '[0-9a-f]{38}$' | \
    sed -r 's,^.*([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])/([0-9a-f]{38}),\1\2,'
  ```
- If you on Linux/Mac: make it executable: `chmod a+x all-objects.sh`
- Remember some small part of the missing data (string, method name, ...)
- Find this part changing `grep` parameter in the following script

  ```
  for rev in $(./s.sh) ; do
    C=$(git show $rev | grep <METHOD_NAME_OR_SOMETHING_FROM_MISSING_FILE> )
    if [[ "$C" != "" ]] ; then
      echo $rev
      echo $C
    fi
  done
  ```

Comment: Another useful trick: run `git fsck` and look for `dangling blob`s.  If files were `git add`ed but never `git commit`ed, and then later removed from the index but not yet garbage-collected, they will be "dangling blobs".